# how to define a global boolean array in Netbeans? What are the imports required?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, netbeans-8

I wrote this code for one of my recent projects, but as I am new at Netbeans, on declaring a boolean array globally, as shown below, I am getting an error.

```
boolean[] car1=new boolean[25];
car1[0]=true;
```

is showing the error

```
create class "car1" in package
create class "main_file" in package
```

I tried to declare it inside the events, where i did that peace fully but i couldn't do it just above main function.

Comment: Is that one line the entirety of your Java file?

Comment: Can you paste the whole file here? You don't need any imports to declare an array.

Comment: The trick, to understand why an error happens, is to read (and post) the error message. And NetBeans is a tool to help you write Java. The language is Java. Whether you write it with NetBeans or with another tool is irrelevant. What matters is that you respect the Java syntax and rules.

Comment: you could set a break point where this boolean array is created and run your project in debug mode then step through it and check your variables to see where exactly your error occurs.  That might help you to figure it out on your own.  Debugging is a good skill to have  anyway!

Comment: @BigT: debugging non-compiling code won't work.

Comment: `create class "car1" in package` is not a complete error message (it doesn't even look like part of an error message to me, but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Blah {

    public static boolean[] newBooleanArray = new boolean[25];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        newBooleanArray[0] = true;

    }
}
```

Define the boolean array outside of any method, and give it a visibility modifier (public, private, protected, etc). If you are using it in a static method (like my main method above), also add the static modifier. The above code was tested and working.